How to read information coming from RS232 on Arduino ATMEGA2560-PRO-CH340 on custom baud rate?
➡️The problem is next: I can't read and send information properly on current baud rate, which is 96050. This is the baud rate of a device, with which I want to communicate, but for now I can't, because it needs to be fixed.
That's why I use Arduino ATMEGA2560-PRO-CH340 and RS232 converter (this is how it looks: https://www.anodas.lt/image/cache/catalog/AN3/rs232-uart-keitiklis-su-db9-jungtimi-sp3232-3-3v-5v-waveshare-3965-204849-500x500.jpg) to simulate the process.
I simply connected RS 232 converter to Arduino. So, I send data from my PC by RS232 to Arduino, which is reading the incoming data and simply send it back to PC by RS232 on 96050 BAUD rate.
⚠️NOTES:⚠️

The message that I send is simple "Hello, world" string
I use Terminal v1.93b by Br@y++ to send the string
To see the package (Bytes in HEX and system codes) and difference in time I use HDD Software Device Monitor Studio V8.47.00.10357
Other port settings are default: 8 data bits, no parity, no handshaking, 1 stop bit

The sketch below allows me to send and receive data back properly, but ONLY then I close the port .
#define BAUD_RATE_CUSTOM 96050

char symbolToRead;
boolean isRead = false;
String strToRead = "";

void setup() 
{
  Serial1.begin(BAUD_RATE_CUSTOM);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(Serial1.available())
  {
    symbolToRead = Serial1.read();
    strToRead += symbolToRead;
    isRead = true;
  }
  if (isRead)
  {
    Serial1.print(strToRead);
    strToRead = "";
    Serial1.end();
  }
}

I don't know what is happening under the cover of IDE, but when I send the information via RS232 port monitor with macros, during some short period of time I can get my "Hello, world" back. But the Terminal v1.93b by Br@y++ in such a case shows next: яHello, worldHello, world<0>. Meanwhile studio shows this: 
➡️0 - first message.
➡️1,2,3 - manual input. I was simply pressing the button until <0> symbol appeared (the last one on the image).
The weird thing is that this is, for now, the only way to receive data and send in correctly, because when I tried something regular like this:
#define BAUD_RATE_CUSTOM 96050

char symbolToRead;
boolean isRead = false;
String strToRead = "";

void setup() 
{
  Serial1.begin(BAUD_RATE_CUSTOM);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(Serial1.available())
  {
    symbolToRead = Serial1.read();
    strToRead += symbolToRead;
    isRead = true;
  }
  if (isRead)
  {
    Serial1.print(strToRead);
    strToRead = "";
    // simply remove Serial1.end() here
  }
}

The RS232 monitor in such a case on my PC shows next:

HEX -> 6F 75 6F 6F 6F AF BF 77 6F 7B 6F 77
SYMBOLS -> ouoooЇїwo{ow

I simply was expecting to receive normal "Hello, world" string. I checked Arduino, converter logic (I thought that it might be inverted, but it works fine). With default baud rates like 9600 and 115200 works fine, but I need specific 96050, because, as I wrote above, this is the baud rate of device with which I will communicate.
I also tried to use Serial.write(), buffer with Serial.readBytes(), but they were leading to the same ouoooЇїwo{ow result.
Maybe there is a thing with timing of writing and reading, maybe 16MHz frequency simply gives a huge percentage of errors on 96050 baud rate, but then why I can receive the "Hello, world" while I am closing the port 
So, I hope that some of you will be able to solve such a weird case. Any help will be appreciated with a sincere virtual hug 

I have never seen a device that runs at 96050 baud. Are you sure you shouldn't be using 9600 baud, a very common value?

I am sure. That device is ultrasound generator. Such baud rate it's written in documentation to it. If I was able to use 9600, well, I would not ask such a question

So, the answer is simple. The device, actually, has a setting to 9600 baud rate. It was just not working properly on physical level. Now everything is going well and my sketch here is no longer relevant.
And the problem with such a baud rate is purely based on physics. In order to transfer data without huge error percentage, which is close to 5% on 16Mhz, the frequency should be higher.
